# Safari/WebKit's console.log DOM node as object?

Tags: javascript, dom, safari

This is something that's been driving me nuts for a while. When I console.log a DOM node (returned by example from `document.getElementById`), it appears as an interactive html element, as it would appear on the "Elements" tab.

This can be handy for sure, but there are times when I just want to be able to expand the object and see all of its properties, like I can do for every other kind of object I log to the console.

Is there *any* way I can get a DOM node to display in the console as a regular object??

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `console.dir` instead of `console.log`.

```
console.log( document.body );
<body class="question-page">...</body>

console.dir( document.body );
> HTMLBodyElement
    aLink: ""
    attributes: NamedNodeMap
    background: ""
    ...
```

[From the Firebug docs:](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API)

> **console.dir(object)**
>
> Prints an interactive listing of all properties of the object. This looks identical to the view that you would see in the DOM tab.

Chrome supports `console.dir` as well, [as shown here](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html) *(not shown as a property of `console`, but it is available)*.

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Despite my searches and reading through Apple's docs, console.dir was not mentioned anywhere, but it works perfectly!

Comment: @chaiguy: I've got to admit, I'm really glad you asked this question. I've always wondered the same thing, but never searched around for it. I would always double wrap my elements in Arrays, like `[[document.body]]`. This works, but you need to expand the inner Array to get to the element object. `dir` is much nicer! :o)

Comment: The irony is I could have just console-logged `console` and checked its prototype. I love JavaScript. :)